# How to display progress bar? multithreading java

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, compiler-errors, jprogressbar

I'm a beginner in java so sorry if I'm asking a stupid question , but how do I make a new thread in my gui class that would create a progress bar. I have a class named progress and made  a new thread in my gui class using the constructor that I have created. But for some reason, I am getting a strange error:

```
"constructor progress in class NewJFrame.progress cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: JProgressBar
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

NewJframe.java

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
           if (jRadioButton1.isSelected()){   

          App m = new App();


      Thread t1 = new Thread(new progress(jProgressBar1));
      m.sendPingRequest2("104.160.142.3",jTextPane1,jTextPane2,jTextField1);


} 
    }
```

progress.java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author User
 */


import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
public class progress implements Runnable {


      private static int DELAY = 500;


  JProgressBar progressBar;



  public  progress (JProgressBar bar) {
    progressBar = bar;
  }


  public void run() {
    int minimum = progressBar.getMinimum();
    int maximum = progressBar.getMaximum();
    for (int i = minimum; i < maximum; i++) {
      try {
        int value = progressBar.getValue();
        progressBar.setValue(value + 1);

        Thread.sleep(DELAY);
      } catch (InterruptedException ignoredException) {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please read about Java naming conventions. Class names go UpperCase. Always.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 3) And to emphasize the wise words of @GhostCat: Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
Thread t1= new progress ( jProgressBar1);
```

Should be:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new progress(jProgressBar1));
```

since your progress class implements Runnable and does not extend Thread.

Also your error message is strange:

> constructor progress in class NewJFrame.progress cannot be applied to given types

suggesting that the problem resides within the constructor of the `NewJFrame.progress` class, a class that looks to be *nested* within the NewJFrame class. If this is so, get rid of the nested class and only deal with the free-standing progress (re-name it "Progress" please) class.

---

But having said that, your code has potential problems as you're changing the state of the JProgressBar, a Swing component, directly from within a background thread, and this is not Swing thread-safe. Much better to use a SwingWorker and link it to the JProgressBar's state as per the [JProgressBar standard tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) (check the link please).

For example:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ProgressFun extends JPanel {
    private JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);

    public ProgressFun() {
        progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
        final JButton startProgress = new JButton("Start Progress");
        startProgress.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_S);
        startProgress.addActionListener(l -> {
            startProgress.setEnabled(false);
            progressBar.setValue(0);
            final MyWorker myWorker = new MyWorker();
            myWorker.execute();

            myWorker.addPropertyChangeListener(pcEvent -> {
                if (pcEvent.getPropertyName().equals("progress")) {
                    int value = (int) pcEvent.getNewValue();
                    progressBar.setValue(value);
                } else if (pcEvent.getNewValue() == SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE) {
                    startProgress.setEnabled(true);
                    try {
                        myWorker.get();
                    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        add(progressBar);
        add(startProgress);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        ProgressFun mainPanel = new ProgressFun();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Progress Fun");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}

class MyWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        int progress = 0;
        setProgress(progress);
        while (progress < 100) {
            progress += (int)(5 * Math.random());
            progress = Math.min(progress, 100);
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep((int) (500 * Math.random()));
            setProgress(progress);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

As an aside, you will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others.

Comment: You may also want to consider [`ProgressMonitor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ProgressMonitor.html) as a possible alternative way to display a progress bar.

Comment: hmm still getting same error , i will try with swingworker. Thanks anyways

Comment: @ronaldshirman: the error is strange -- it's stating the the error is `"... in class NewJFrame.progress..."` suggesting that you might have **two** progress classes, one free standing that you are showing us, and  a different one that is nested within the NewJFrame class that you are *not* showing us. If this is so, then you're needlessly confusing yourself (and us) by doing this, and you will want to get rid of the nested class.

Comment: @KevinAnderson It’s a personal thing, but I’ve never really liked the ProgressMonitor, but that’s me

Comment: HI , it seems to work  now ,  thanks for the help , but why is the thread only starting after the  pingrequest  function ?  shouldnt they happen at the same time?

Comment: @ronald the ping request is blocking code. As with any blocking code the only way for them to occur at the same time is to call in separate threads